# SVG generated in vue-app has pattern-offset in Illustrator

Tags: svg, vue-cli

When I generate SVGs in my vue-app and open them in Illustrator the patterns are offset to the right and slightly down.

I tried to google the problem, but I was only able to find stuff about exporting from Illustrator for the web, not the other way around.
I also tried to generate the SVG more like Illustrator would, but I can't figure out how Illustrator comes up with those transform-matrix values.

This is the SVG generated by the app with only the pattern and a background in it:

```
<svg
  id="previewSvg"
  version="1.1"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  xml:space="preserve"
  x="0px"
  y="0px"
  width="5000"
  height="2500"
  viewBox="0 0 5000 2500"
>
  <defs>
    <pattern
      id="BrickWall"
      y="0"
      width="40"
      height="38"
      viewBox="0 0 40 38"
      patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
      style=""
      x="0"
      patternTransform="matrix(10,0,0,-10,0,0)"
    >
      <rect
        width="40"
        height="2"
        x="0"
        y="0"
        fill="White"
      ></rect>
      <rect
        width="2"
        height="18"
        x="38"
        y="2"
        fill="White"
      ></rect>
      <rect
        width="38"
        height="2"
        x="0"
        y="18"
        fill="White"
      ></rect>
      <rect
        width="2"
        height="18"
        x="18"
        y="20"
        fill="White"
      ></rect>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <g>
    <rect
      width="5000"
      height="2500"
      fill="Maroon"
      fill-opacity="1"
    ></rect>
    <rect
      width="5000"
      height="2500"
      fill="url(#BrickWall)"
      fill-opacity="0.75"
    ></rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

This is the same SVG after saving it in Illustrator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 22.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="previewSvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 5000 2500" style="enable-background:new 0 0 5000 2500;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:none;}
    .st1{fill:#FFFFFF;}
    .st2{fill:#800000;}
    .st3{fill:url(#SVGID_1_);fill-opacity:0.75;}
</style>
<pattern  y="2500" width="40" height="38" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="BrickWall" viewBox="0 -38 40 38" style="overflow:visible;">
    <g>
        <rect y="-38" class="st0" width="40" height="38"/>
        <rect y="-2" class="st1" width="40" height="2"/>
        <rect x="38" y="-20" class="st1" width="2" height="18"/>
        <rect y="-20" class="st1" width="38" height="2"/>
        <rect x="18" y="-38" class="st1" width="2" height="18"/>
    </g>
</pattern>
<g>
    <rect class="st2" width="5000" height="2500"/>
    <pattern  id="SVGID_1_" xlink:href="#BrickWall" patternTransform="matrix(10 0 0 10 51318 95640)">
    </pattern>
    <rect class="st3" width="5000" height="2500"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Illustrator changes a lot of stuff when opening the SVG, but that's irrelevant, since the look stays the same for pretty much everything else I use except for the patterns.

I expect Illustrator to start the pattern at the same point as the browser does, which is the top left of the element the pattern is applied to.

Comment: What's the question? Illustrator is incorrectly importing a pattern - it's changing the viewBox of the pattern for no good reason I can imagine. You'd need access to Illustrator source to figure out why.

Comment: Illustrator's SVG import filter has many limitations. And you are likely hitting one of those limitations.  If you can, try simplifying your pattern as much as possible.  Ie. try generating patterns that don't use `patternTransform` or `viewBox`.